# is there away to count how many users have a certain option from the SQL db

Tags: c#, sql

I am have a database with options with 1 to many relationship, for example

```
Company,username,Option,QTY

CompanyA,john,Option1,3
CompanyA,john,Option2,3
CompanyA,frank,Option2,3

CompanyB,jim,Option2,2
CompanyB,jim,Option3,2
```

I am trying to get a count

So it should give a result like this

```
Company A - 6 Option1 and Option 2
Company A - 3 Options2


Company B - 2 Options2
Company B -2 Options 3
```

I was able to get the value in SQL view, but just not sure best way to get the value in the format so I can get all the variable options per company ?

Comment: Did you look at Group By and Sum sql statements?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you looking more or less for a pivotting approach

```
SELECT 
   table.Company
 , SUM(CASE WHEN table.Option = 'option1' THEN table.QTY ELSE 0 END) AS Option1
 , SUM(CASE WHEN table.Option = 'option2' THEN table.QTY ELSE 0 END) AS Option2
FROM 
 table 
GROUP BY 
 table.Company
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, if the options are dynamic is there a way to loop through and get all the variances per user and company?

Comment: *" if the options are dynamic is there a way to loop through and get all the variances per user and company?"* @Joester80 not possible to answer because ANSI/ISO SQL standard  where the questions tag `sql` is about didn't defined dynamic queries.. You should check which database you are using and edit the question with a more specific database tag like `SQL Server`, `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL` for example, which might extended the SQL support by allowing dynamic queries

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it manually:

```
int count = 0;
foreach(Company c in Companies) // Companies = the data you "withdraw" from the database
    if (Company.Option == OptionWanted)
        sum++;
```

Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: I think so, basically I need to get a count of all users for the company that have the same options. for example 400 users will have the defaults 20 users will have option 1 and 2 selected, 5 users have selected option 1 only and 10 users selected option 3 was trying to figure out best way to get those counts

Comment: This description does not match what you posted as the expected output, can you be clear what you actually want and what `QTY` is for?

Comment: Hi, a user profile will select the options for an order and the qty they want delivered each week.  So User 1 has selected qty of 2 orders.  I just want a way to show the how many users for company A have selected any variance of options, and the same for each other company

Comment: I'm confused.. What?